# Orthogonality on Banach spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I got a doubt with a proof in Brezis' Functional Analysis, theorem 2.16. It says

> **Theorem 2.16**: Let $G,L \subset E$ be two closed subspaces in a Banach space $E$. Then the following properties are equivalent:
>
> (a) $G+L$ is closed
>
> (b) $G^{\perp}+L^{\perp}$ is closed
>
> (c) $G+L=(G^{\perp}\cap L^{\perp})^{\perp}$

it says more propositions, but I'm interested in these ones, actually just in $(b)$ implies $(c)$. It says we have $(a)\Longleftrightarrow (b) \Longleftrightarrow (c)$ because of:

$$
\overline{G+L}=(G^{\perp}\cap L^{\perp})^{\perp}
$$

Any hint in order to understand this would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a proof in the book. What is unclear about it?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. What I don't get is that they say $(a)\Longleftrightarrow (b) \Longleftrightarrow (c)$ because of $\overline{G+L}=(G^{\perp} \cap L^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book does **not** say that $(a)\iff (b)\iff (c)$ because of $$\overline{G+L}=(G^{\perp}\cap L^{\perp})^{\perp} \tag{19}$$
It says that $(a)\iff   (c)$ because of (19). The implication $(b)\implies (a)$ is proved later, and takes about a page.

$(a)\implies (c)$. If (a) holds, then $G+L=\overline{G+L}=(G^{\perp}\cap L^{\perp})^{\perp}$, so (c) holds.

$(c)\implies (a)$. If (c) holds, then $G+L$ is closed because for any set $A\in E^*$, the annihilator $A^\perp$ is closed. (It's the intersection of the zero sets of the linear functionals that belong to $A$.)